# Can't view variable value as simple test in SocialEngine

Tags: php, model-view-controller, widget, socialengine

My code inside Controller.php is:

```
<?php

class Widget_TestWidgetController extends Engine_Content_Widget_Abstract
{
  public function indexAction()
  {
    $this->view->msg('Test Widget');
  }
}
```

And in index.tpl is:

```
<?php
    echo $this->msg;
?>
```

I've uploaded all the skeleton of the widgets I'd downloaded and have gone to Layout->Layout Editor and put that simple widget into page, but it doesn't show the message I've sent from controller to view, however other widgets that are for SocialEngine itself, works correctly.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The structure of my method in controller was wrong:

```
$this->view->msg('Test Widget'); => $this->view->msg = 'Test Widget';
```